# Abrir enlace en pop up

Tags: javascript, html, css

el problema es que tengo ese codigo y trabaja bien con etiquetas de imagen de parrafo y encabezado pero con enlace no me carga solo queda en vacio...

```css
 .img-contenedor {  
    position: fixed;  
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;  
    top: 0;  
    right: 0;  
    bottom: 0;  
    left: 0;  
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.8);  
    z-index: 99999;  
    opacity:0;  
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;  
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;  
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in;  
    pointer-events: none; 
    } 
    
    .img-contenedor:target {  
    opacity:1;  
    pointer-events: auto; 
    } 
    
    .img-contenedor > div {  
    width: 90%; 
    heigth: auto; 
    position: relative;  
    margin: 30% auto;  
    padding: 0px;  
    border-radius: 10px;  
    background: #fff;  
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);  
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#fff, #999);  
    background: -o-linear-gradient(#fff, #999); 
    -webkit-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; 
    -moz-transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; 
    transition: opacity 400ms ease-in; 
    }
    .imagenropa a {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 9px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 9px;  
    border-radius: 9px;  
    }
    .close {  
    background: #606061;  
    color: #FFFFFF;  
    line-height: 25px;  
    position: absolute;  
    right: -12px;  
    text-align: center;  
    top: -10px;  
    width: 24px;  
    text-decoration: none;  
    font-weight: bold;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 15px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 15px;  
    border-radius: 15px;  
    -moz-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;  
    -webkit-box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000;  
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px #000; 
    } 
    
    .close:hover { 
    background: #00d9ff; }
```

```html
<a href="#imgZoom">
   <img src="link de mi sexi botón">
   </a>
   <div id="imgZoom" class="img-contenedor">  
   <div>  
   <a href="#close" title="Close" class="close">X</a>   
   <div class="imagenropa"> 
   <a href="link que quiero quese abra pero no puedo porque tengo 8 dias apenas aprendiendo html"></a>
    </div>
   </div> </div>
```

Comment: Hola, me imagino que lo que tienes en tu etiqueta <a> es una imagen y no se muestra. prueba a cambiar la etiqueta <a> por <img>.

Comment: Hola fran si efectivamente el link es a una img pero el problema es que es una img con un peso de 5mb y son varias img entonces tendria una pagina de unos 500mb solo en pop ups  y necesito que se abran como enlace para que se cargen hasta que el usuario le de click al vista previa es para una tienda y necesito que sea li mas rapido posible. @Csharls

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Si estás trabajando con Bootstrap puedes usar modales, veo que lo que buscas es darle velocidad a tu página mostrando primero **thumbnail**s y no llamar la imagen original sino hasta que el usuario lo solicite.

Puedes probar con el siguiente snippet, adaptándolo a tu código y necesidad.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" id="bootstrap-css">
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>

<div class="container">

<div class="row">

<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pop-up-1">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/YZ7AGyF.jpg" width="150" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="">
</a>

<hr>

<!-- Thumbnail link for lion image -->
<a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target=".pop-up-2">
<img src="http://i.imgur.com/dtaHtds.jpg" width="150" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="">
</a>


<!--  Modal content for the mixer image example -->
  <div class="modal fade pop-up-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel-1" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel-1">Mixer Board</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/YZ7AGyF.jpg.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="">
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal mixer image -->
 
 <!--  Modal content for the lion image example -->
  <div class="modal fade pop-up-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel-2" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
          <h4 class="modal-title" id="myLargeModalLabel-2">Lion</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <img src="http://i.imgur.com/kzGVqbd.jpg" class="img-responsive img-rounded center-block" alt="">
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
  </div><!-- /.modal mixer image -->
  
    
</div> <!-- /.row -->
</div> <!-- /.container -->
```

---

[Fuente](https://bootsnipp.com/iframe/8ObW)